# Getting a 405 response: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to set up a Laravel route and it is throwing a 405, method not allowed. I am unsure why it is doing this as everything I have done seems correct? I have even tried changing the route URI but still results in the same issue.

Checked out the `class RouteCollection extends AbstractRouteCollection` and it seems to be registering it correctly.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user', 'UserController@get')->name('user'); // this one
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function get(Request $request)
    {
        dd('hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why I have been down voted? My question seems valid.

Comment: from where are you trying to access this route?

Comment: I'm using Insomnia as a rest client.

Comment: which route you are trying to access? Remove middleware to debug correctly. Maybe your middleware redirects somewhere

Comment: Could you share with us your full routes/api.php file also a screen shot from insomnia

Comment: It's very possible you're making a GET request to that route....am more interested in seeing how you made that call to that route.